# How does the history command work?

Tags: command-line, bash, bash-history

When I type any command in the terminal, it doesn't appear in my `~/.bash_history` file until I exit my session.

Also, when I manually edit my `~/.bash_history` file (for example I remove the last three commands), when I type `history` it still shows the commands that I removed from the `~/.bash_history` file. Only when I exit my session and login again they disappear.

How does my `~/.bash_history` file and the `history` command get synchronized?

Comment: it's in RAM... [Where is bash's history stored?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/145250)

Comment: "When I type any command in the terminal" Not actually true. When you put a space in front of the command by default it does not save that command.

Comment: @Rinzwind the behavior of saving the command even if it has a space in front can be changed by editing the value of your HISTCONTROL environment variable.

Comment: @sys0dm1n "by default"

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When you open a bash terminal it loads the content of `~/.bash_history` and builds the active shell's history (in the RAM), adding every command executed in that shell to it – and only to it, not to the file.

Only when you close a bash terminal its history is appended to your `~/.bash_history` file.

---

#### Options of `history`:

```
history -a # save the active shell's history to ~/.bash_history (appending)
history -c # clear the active shell's history
history -d NNN # delete row NNN of the active shell's history
history -r # reload the active shell's history from ~/.bash_history (appending)
history -w # save the active shell's history to ~/.bash_history (overwriting)
```

---

#### Options for `~/.bashrc` file

If you want to change this behaviour so that the temporary history is saved to `~/.bash_history` directly after executing a command, add this line:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a"
```

If you additionally want every terminal to automatically load the `~/.bash_history` file after every command execution, add this line instead:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND="history -a; history -c; history -r"
```

If you want to exclude certain commands (e.g. everything beginning with `sudo` and `cat`) from being saved, add this line:

```
HISTIGNORE="sudo*:cat*"
```